# what is the error this question,please explain me

Tags: mysql, sql

```
CREATE TABLE doctor(
    Did varchar(30) not null,
    spid int,
    Hid int,
    Dname varchar(200)not null,
    Dnumber int,
    fee decimal(10,2)not null,
    constraint primary key(Did),
    constraint unique(Did,Dname),
    constraint foreign key(spid)references speciality(spid)
    on delete cascade on update cascade, 
    constraint foreign key(Hid)references hospital(Hid)
    on delete cascade on update cascade
    )engine=innodb;
```

Comment: Please [edit] the question to add the text of the error message.

Comment: And you should tell us what DBMS you are using.

Comment: If your error relates to FKs (and it appears it does since without them in your table definition there is no syntax error) then you need to provide definitions for the referenced tables.

Comment: The conditions for creating foreign keys can be found https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/create-table-foreign-keys.html

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to give an answer without the error message or your version of mysql, but I'd recommend to be sure that spid column of speciality is also defined is int, not int(11) or unsigned int(and also for other foreign key references). 
And also your primary key is already always unique, I don't see any point including that in another unique constraint.

Comment: This is more suitable as a comment than an answer